# Showing that $C^{-1}B(C^{-1}B+(AC)^{-1})^{-1}$ has real eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $\Sigma$ is a real-valued covariance matrix partitioned into equal-sized blocks as follows
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
A&C\\
C^T&B
\end{matrix}\right)
=
\Sigma
$$

The following matrices are not symmetric yet [seem](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-real-eigs.nb) to always have real eigenvalues, can anyone see a way to prove this?

$$D_1=C^{-1}B(C^{-1}B+(AC)^{-1})^{-1}$$
$$D_2=(BC^{-T}+CA^{-1})^{-1}CA^{-1}$$

Comment: One things to check is whether these matrices happen to be similar to something positive definite.

Comment: @BenGrossmann btw, recently saw that a product of $k$ random matrices will be not symmetric, but will have real eigenvalues for large $k$. Is there an intuitive understanding of signfiicance of non-symmetric matrix having real eigenvalues? https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.06256

Comment: Interesting. My instinct is to think about this in terms of the characteristic polynomial: in principle, the characteristic polynomial of a non-symmetric matrix (with real entries) can be any polynomial (with real coefficients). So, the question becomes: what structure is being imposed on this polynomial that is causing it to have real roots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $D_1$ has real eigenvalues iff $D_1^{-1}$ has real eigenvalues. We find that
$$
D_1^{-1} = (C^{-1}B + (AC)^{-1})B^{-1}C = 
C^{-1}BB^{-1}C + C^{-1}A^{-1}B^{-1}C\\
= I + C^{-1}A^{-1}B^{-1}C.
$$
So, it suffices to show that $D_1^{-1} - I = C^{-1}A^{-1}B^{-1}C$ always has real eigenvalues. We note that this matrix is similar to
$$
C(D_1^{-1} - I)C^{-1} = C[C^{-1}A^{-1}B^{-1}C]C^{-1} = A^{-1}B^{-1},
$$
which is in turn similar to
$$
A^{1/2}A^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1/2} = A^{-1/2}B^{-1}A^{-1/2}.
$$
So, we see that $D_1^{-1} - I$ is similar to $A^{-1/2}B^{-1}A^{-1/2}$. $B$ is a principal submatrix of a positive definite matrix and is therefore positive definite, which means that $B^{-1}$ is positive definite, which means that $A^{-1/2}B^{-1}A^{-1/2} = [A^{-1/2}]^TB^{-1}A^{-1/2}$ is positive definite, which means that $A^{-1/2}B^{-1}A^{-1/2}$ has real eigenvalues, which means that $D_1^{-1} - I$ has real eigenvalues.

A similar line of reasoning can be applied to $D_2$.

Comment: You seem to imply that $A^{-1/2}\left(AC^{-1}B^{-1}C\right)A^{-1/2}$ is equal or similar to $\left(AC^{-1}B^{-1}C\right)$. Is that so? I would have thought it ought to be $A^{-1/2}\left(AC^{-1}B^{-1}C\right)A^{+1/2}$, or something like it

Comment: @Cryo you’re right, that was a careless error. Not sure if I can fix this answer

Comment: There's a typo in first line -- $(AC)^{-1}$ became $AC^{-1}$

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov That was the big mistake! Good catch. See my latest edit; I think the same argument works now.

Comment: Assuming I didn't make any mistakes this time, this all means that $[A^{1/2}C]D_1[A^{1/2}C]^{-1}$ is positive definite, which gives you an alternate (perhaps quicker) proof.