# Polar decomposition when basis is allowed to vary?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I'm free to chose a basis $P$ for my input matrix $A$ before applying polar decomposition, how do I find a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) $P$ such that the rotation factor of polar decomposition becomes as close to identity as possible?

We know that $1/\sqrt{2}$ of random 2D matrices [admit a basis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7601) where $U$ is the identity matrix, I'm curious about the distribution of angles in the remaining 30%

related [q](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4744629/geometric-interpretation-of-a-non-symmetric-matrix-having-only-real-eigenvalues)

Comment: Note that having real eigenvalues doesn't allow a change of basis in which $U$ is the identity matrix; for the standard polar decomposition, we would also require  the eignvalues of the matrix to be non-negative.

Comment: @BenGrossmann doesn't real eigenvalue allow similarity transformation into matrix that is positive semi-definite? So the rotation factor of that matrix would be the identity

Comment: No: similarity transformations preserve eigenvalues, and positive semidefinite matrices have non-negative eigenvalues. A matrix with a negative, real eigenvalue cannot be similar to a positive semidefinite matrix.

Comment: You might be able to use this ideas of angles in this context, however, if you modify the polar decomposition such that $P$ is required only to be symmetric. I suspect (based completely on conjecture) that the relaxation on $P$ can be accounted for by a restriction on $U$ that its eigenvalues should have non-negative real part.

Comment: @BenGrossmann hm, I was confused by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3906484/showing-that-c-1bc-1bac-1-1-has-real-eigenvalues#comment8056732_3906484) where you show that matrix has real eigenvalues by showing it's similar to positive definite. I guess such existence is sufficient condition for real eigenvalues but not necessary?

Comment: Exactly right. As it so happened in that case, the eigenvalues of the matrices $D_i$ were necessarily positive

Comment: Another trick that might be noteworthy here: if $A$ has real eigenvalues, then there exists a constant $k$ (for example, $k = \|A\|$ for any typical matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$) such that $A + kI$ will have non-negative eigenvalues, from which it follows that $A + kI$ is similar to a positive semidefinite matrix.